# Parquet file being read as empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, parquet

I'm trying to read a parquet file that I downloaded from the HDFS on my Jupyter notebook however it is showing up as empty. I know it is not empty because I had worked on it prior to saving it to the HDFS. Does anyone know why it is being read as empty?

The size of the file on the HDFS and cluster environment:

```
hadoop fs -du -s -h /user/some/test.parquet
1.2 M  3.5 M  /user/some/test.parquet

val test = spark.read.parquet("hdfs:///user/some/test.parquet")

test.count()
res0: Long = 10
```

On an almond-kernel in Jupyter notebook to work in Scala.

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

import org.apache.spark.sql._

val spark = {
    SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
}

def sc = spark.sparkContext

val test = spark.read.parquet("/Users/me/some/test.parquet")
test: DataFrame = [UnitId: string, GeoId: string ... 26 more fields]

test.count()
res28: Long = 0L
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's interested, I figured out the issue.
I had downloaded the parquet file from the HDFS using "hadoop fs -getmerge", resulting in the corruption of the file.

The right approach when dealing with the parquet file would be to "hadoop fs -get.